# Flutter cannot able to run the project

Tags: flutter

Error

```
BUILD FAILED in 10s
  Command: D:\flutterProjects\meetdaxdemodk\android\gradlew.bat app:propertie
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

When I try to run a project I am getting a Gradle error. How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Is this an older project with an recently updated Flutter version or is this a new project? If it's an older project try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated

Comment: this is a new project

Comment: What Flutter version?

Comment: channel version v1.0.0

Comment: Perhaps something went wrong when you create the project. Try deleting `android/` and run `flutter create .` If you made manual changes in this directory you need to re-apply them.

Comment: i deleted android folder in my flutter project

Comment: after deleting also i am getting the same error

Comment: I have seen similar issues recently with Gradle wrapper, but I don't know what causes them or how to work around. Perhaps one more suggestion. Try to change `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` `distributionUrl`  from `4.10.2` to `4.10.3`.

Comment: after changing the version 4.10.2 into 4.10.3 i am getting same error

Comment: please tell me some other solution i wasted my whole day with this i can't able to run my project